# Import a XML file into an HTML page and then i want use DOM on the tags of XML imported

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, import

I have a little (i think :) ) problem.
I have a page HTML called `index.html` like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="MyButtons">
 Here there are some buttons that call some javascripts functinons of file script.js
</body>

</html>
```

Then i have also a simple XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
 <testo>
  <paragrafo id="p_01">
    <soggetto>Steve</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> a <complemento>man</complemento>.
    <soggetto>Mark</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> another <complemento>man</complemento>.
  </paragrafo>

  <paragrafo id="p_02">
    <soggetto>Tony</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> a <complemento>cousin of Steve</complemento>.
    <soggetto>Maria</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> another <complemento>cousinf of Steve</complemento>.
  </paragrafo>
  .
  .
  .other elements <paragrafo>
  .
  .
</testo>
```

I have created my personal tag like `<testo>, <soggetto>, <verbo>` ecc.

I want that onClick on a my button in `div="MyButton"` launch an hypothetical function javascript `loadXML('file.xml',"divId")` that copy all the content of `file.xml` (text and tag) and put it on a div whit id="divId"(that the function `loadXML` creates) in the body of `index.html`.
After the `loadXML` function i want that my html page look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="divId">

  <testo>
    <paragrafo id="p_01">
     <soggetto>Steve</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> a <complemento>man</complemento>.
     <soggetto>Mark</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> another <complemento>man</complemento>.
    </paragrafo>

    <paragrafo id="p_02">
     <soggetto>Tony</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> a <complemento>cousin of Steve</complemento>.
     <soggetto>Maria</soggetto> <verbo>is</verbo> another <complemento>cousinf of Steve</complemento>.
    </paragrafo>
    .
    .
    .other elements <paragrafo>
    .
    .
 </testo>

 </div>

 <div id="MyButtons">
  Here there are some buttons that call some javascripts functinons of file script.js
 </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

In this way after i want use the buttons of index.html for call functions that use `document.getElementById('p_01');` and other function of `DOM`, as if the content of file.xml was already in the default page index.html.

How i can write the funciont `loadXML("file.xml","divID")` to do this?
I hope you can help me, please are days that i try to do this without any result :(

Thank you at all !!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in to `Microsoft.XMLDOM` FOR IE and 
`document.implementation.createDocument()`

To load xml document you could do the following.

```
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
    var xmldoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     }else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){
       xmldoc=document. implementation.createDocument("", "doc", null);
    }
   xmldoc.async = false;
   xmldoc.load("file.xml");
```

you will need to do bit of work to get the nodes

Comment: I have try it yet but don't work 'function loadXML(filename){
var error = "";
var file = filename;
try //Internet Explorer
{ xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 xmlDoc.async=false;
 xmlDoc.load(filename);}
catch(e)
{ try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
 { xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.load(filename);}
 catch(e)
 {try //Google Chrome
  {var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
   xmlDoc =xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;}
  catch(e)
  {error=e.message;}
 }}}'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. The problem is that getElementById works only on HTML DOM objects, and "paragrafo" is not a valid DOM Object ("p" would be one), I mean, it's not enough to have well-formed html tags, they must also be html **valid** tags.

You should tell us what's happens in the application after the user presses a button? what does the button do?

Comment: When i click for example on the button "button1" all the word that have the tag <verbo> change their color in "red". Each button edit my text, like wordSpacing, line-height, font-size ecc

Answer (score 0):

Many people would like to do what you are doing, but sadly, this isn't the way HTML is moving. Your "little" problem has actually been a very big issue in the standards world over the last year or so. See for example section 2.4 of http://www.w3.org/2010/html-xml/snapshot/